# I'm getting this error while i trying to create and apply yaml file in K8S

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

....error validating data:

> ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers): invalid
> type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec.containers: got "map", expected
> "array"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off
> with --validate=false

this content of my yaml file ;

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: school-service-be
  labels:
    app: school-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: school-service
  template:
    metadata: 
      labels:
        app: school-service
    spec:
      containers:
          name: school-service-be
          image: xxxxxxxxxx
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
              containerPort: 9001
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error PodSpec.containers: got "map", expected "array" or Container.volumeMounts: got "map", expected "array";](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854253/getting-error-podspec-containers-got-map-expected-array-or-container-volum)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Problem. I had to delete minus(-) character inside of "school-service-be" which defines name of metadata...i changed school-service-be with school-service

Comment: This does not solve your problem. You actually miss a `-` under "containers".

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that your yaml code under the `containers` block is a map and not a list. To make it a list you would have to add a "-" in from of the first line under `containers`.

Comment: It's working by deleting "- be " but is it a correct form , i have no idea!!!